# Solving a math exercise

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $a$ and $b$ be two complex numbers such that $|a|=|b|=1$ and $a\neq b$.

Show that for any complex number $z$ that the following number is purely imaginary:
$$
\frac{z + ab\bar{z} -(a+b)}{a-b}
$$

Thank you

Comment: call $u$ this quantity, show $u+\bar u=0$.

Comment: Brutfore: Write all complex numbers in arithmetic form and calculate the fraction. It might help to muliply numerator and denominator with $\overline{a-b}$.

Comment: Thanks @Niklas this might actually be a good way to go, I will see if I can solve the exercise.

Comment: @morfioce I did not try it myself but it might work. (I hope so.) You could check your calculation with wolframalpha easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\displaystyle u=\frac{z+ab\bar z-(a+b)}{a-b}\qquad \bar u=\frac{\bar z+\bar a\bar bz-(\bar a+\bar b)}{\bar a-\bar b}\qquad u+\bar u=\frac {Az+B\bar z+C}{(a-b)(\bar a-\bar b)}$

Note $a\bar a=|a|^2=1$ and $b\bar b=|b|^2=1$

$\begin{cases}
A &=\bar a-\bar b+\bar a\bar b(a-b) &=\bar a-\bar b+\bar b-\bar a &=0\\
B &=ab(\bar a-\bar b)+(a-b) &=b-a+a-b &=0\\
C &=(a+b)(\bar a-\bar b)+(a-b)(\bar a+\bar b) &=(1-a\bar b+b\bar a-1) + (1+a\bar b-b\bar a-1) &=0\\
\end{cases}$

Thus $u+\bar u=0\iff \Re(u)=0$ so $u$ is pure imaginary.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation I really appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prove that $$x = \frac{z + ab\bar{z} -(a+b)}{a-b}$$ is purely imaginary. In other words, $\overline{x} = -x$.
Now, $$\overline{x} = \frac{\overline{z + ab\bar{z} -(a+b)}}{\overline{a-b}} = \frac{\overline{z} + \overline{a}\overline{b}z -(\overline{a}+\overline{b})}{\overline{a}-\overline{b}}.$$
Since $a\overline{a}=b\overline{b}=1$, we have $$\overline{a} = \frac{1}{a}\quad \text{and} \quad \overline{b} = \frac{1}{b}.$$
Therefore,
$$\overline{x} = \frac{\overline{z} + z -(\overline{a}+\overline{b})}{\overline{a}-\overline{b}} = \frac{\overline{z} + z/(ab) -(1/a+1/b)}{1/a-1/b} = \frac{z + ab\bar{z} -(a+b)}{b-a} = -x.$$
Q.E.D.

Comment: This idea of $\bar a=\frac 1a$ to show the symetry in the fraction is nice too.

Comment: thanks @MathLover this is a very elegant solution, kudos.